# Old Namespaces vb.net 2.0

Tags: xml, .net-3.5, soap, x509certificate

I have these namespaces from old code that I am trying to bring over to 3.5. As a result, .NET is not finding them and a lot of my objects aren't defined.

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.Services
Imports Microsoft.Web.Services.Security
Imports Microsoft.Web.Services.Security.X509
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.Xml
Imports System.Xml
```

The ones that don't work are:

```
Microsoft.Web.Services
Microsoft.Web.Services.Security
Microsoft.Web.Services.Security.X509
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml
```

Do you have any idea what these are supposed to be now? The objects that aren't being found are:

```
X509Certificate
SoapEnvelope
SoapContext
X509SecurityToken
SignedXml
Reference
XmlDsigExcC14NTransform
KeyInfo
KeyInfoX509Data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztkw6e67.aspx

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

There's the first one to get you started.

The others can easily be found on MSDN by just searching for the object name.